# How to make button clickable only once in actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have two `scenes` in Flash.

In the first I have a `button` and if somebody `click` on that `button` it goes to the second `scene`.

In the second `scene` I remove the `button` with an image so it is not clickable.

How to leave this `button`, but make it not clickable at all?

and the second case is what if I am using just one `scene` in flash and want the `button` be clickable only once? How the **actionscript** will look like?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ft:Boolean = true;
myBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, action);
function action (e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if(ft)
    {
        myBtn.enabled = false;
        //myBtn.visible = false;
        trace("licked");
        ft = false;
    }
}
```

If as3, try this....

Answer (score 1):

Buttons and MovieClips both have two properties you can use, `enabled` and `visible`. If you want the button to be visible but not clickable, do this:

```
myButton.enabled = false;
```

If you want to hide it altogether and also ensure that it can't be clicked:

```
myButton.visible = false;
```

If this is ActionScript 2.0, just add underscores to the properties:

```
myButton._enabled = false;
myButton._visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.onPress = function()
{ 
  button.enabled = false; 
}
```

Comment: No... it will not work, because **button.enabled = false;**  this will remove the handcursor only.